# How to put a cancel button when connecting

Tags: c#

I make a connection in `C#` with a login and a password and I would like
put a button to cancel the connection to the database if it gets too much
long.

I would like to know how to do it and put it in a thread if possible.

Here is the code:

```
private void btncon_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string strLogin = tblogin.Text.Trim();
    string pass  = tbpwd.Text;
    bool success = false;

    if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(strLogin) || String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(pass))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Veuillez remplir tous les champs SVP ");
    }
    else if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(strLogin) || String.IsNullOrEmpty(pass)){
        MessageBox.Show("Veuillez remplir tous les champs SVP ");
    }
    else
    {
        model.Connexion cm = new model.Connexion();
        pass = Snippets.SHA1Util.SHA1HashStringForUTF8String(pass).ToString();
        string[] user = cm.login(strLogin, pass);    

        if(user[0] != null)
        {
            Int32.TryParse(user[0], out iduser);
            Int32.TryParse(user[1], out idGrp);
            Int32.TryParse(user[2], out idbtq);
            nom = user[3];

            if (idGrp != 3)
                success = true;
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Accès Non autorisé , Veuillez contacter l'administrateur");
                success = false;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Email ou mot de passe incorrect.");
            success = false;
        }
    }

    if (success)
    {                
        main Principale = new main();
        Principale.Show();
        Hide();`
    }
}
```

Comment: Is you app WPF? `cm.login(strLogin, pass)` might take long time? Can you write the code of `cm.login()`?

Comment: It all depends on `cm.login`. If it's a purely synchronous operation that doesn't provide a way to cancel the logon, there isn't much you can do. You could fake it out by doing the login on an another thread, and then providing an async interface with a (cancelation token) to your login code. In the other thread, if the user cancels, you just wait it out and log the user out if the user cancels and the logon eventually succeeds. _But_, if the user cancels and then immediately tries to log in again, you'll end up writing some nasty, bug-producing, code to compensate.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is that when user clicks the `Cancel` button, there is no way to cancel the `cm.login()` method gracefully while it's executing. You could use `Thread.Abort()` to terminate login forcefully, but it's unsafe and strongly discouraged, because making it right would require execute code in another `AppDomain` and would make the code very complicated.

Fortunatelly, you can still implement `Cancel` button, if the following conditions are true:

- It is safe to call `cm.login()` on another thread
- Letting `cm.login()` finish in the background (on another thread) after user clicks on the `Cancel` button does not have undesired effects.

This code also assumes that it is an `Winform` app (but solution for `WPF` app would be very similar). It also assumes that main form has a button `btnCancel` that is hidden (`Visible`=`false`) and it's `Click` event handler is set to `btnCancel_Click` method.

```
TaskCompletionSource<Object> CancelLoginTcs = new TaskCompletionSource<Object>();

// Make button click handler method async
private async void btncon_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        // Make Cancel button visible, so that user can click on it
        btnCancel.Visible = true;

        // Prepare everything needed to start login
        //var strLogin = ...;
        //var pass = ...;
        //model.Connexion cm = new model.Connexion();
        // ...

        // Start login on another thread
        var loginTask = Task<string[]>.Run(() => cm.login(strLogin, pass));

        // Create task that is used to wake-up main thread, when user clicks
        // on the Cancel button before login finishes.
        CancelLoginTcs = new TaskCompletionSource<Object>();

        // Wait for login task or cancel task to complete, whichever finishes first
        await Task.WhenAny(loginTask, CancelLoginTcs.Task);

        if (CancelLoginTcs.Task.IsCanceled)
        {
            // User clicked on the Cancel button.
            // Login method will be running in the background, until it
            // finishes. This assumes that it is safe to do so.
            // Here you should do neccessary clean-up, inform user, etc.
            // ...
        }
        else
        {
            // Login finished and user did NOT click on the Cancel button.

            try
            {
                // Simply read result of login. If an Exception occured during login,
                // it will be rethrow now, so you should handle it appropriatelly
                var user = loginTask.Result;

                // Here program continues in a usual way
                // ...
            }
            catch(Exception E)
            {
                // Handle login exception
                // ...
            }
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        // Hide Cancel button again
        btnCancel.Visible = false;
        CancelLoginTcs = null;
    }
}

private void btnCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Set cancel task to cancelled state. 
    // This will wake-up main thread and let it continue
    CancelLoginTcs.SetCanceled();
}
```